# Convert Webspell CMS site to Joomla CMS site

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have a Webspell CMS gaming site and would like to convert it to use the Joomla CMS system.  My main sites is done in Joomla and I love it.  The only reason I'm using the Webspell CMS is because of the "TEAM" features it has for our teams.

www.teamsyops.com is the site I want to convert to a Joomla backend with all the functions of Webspell.

Comment: ... and the website is still running with webspell ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big job, and Joomla has it's seperate way of doing things which won't interact with Webspell. Personally, i'd stick with the CMS that works, unless you want functionality that only Joomla has to offer.